# setParameters failed when initializing android webcam with python and SL4A

Tags: android, python, webcam, sl4a

I'm using the SL4A platform on an android 4.0 tablet and attempting to initialize a webcam stream using the `droid.webcamStart()` method found here: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference#webcamStart my problem is when I execute the following code I get a setParameters failed error.

The python code is simple:

```
 import android
 droid = android.Android()
 address = droid.webcamStart(100,80,0).result
```

if all goes according to plan this should initialize a webcam preview stream but instead I am getting an error stating:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
```

I've seen other posts somewhat related to this same issue however the developers were using java for development, not python.  What can I do to fix this issue in python?

Thanks

Comment: What cameras do you have on your tablet? It looks like SL4A only supports the default back facing camera, so if you don't have one it will fail.

Comment: I have a front and back facing camera on the tablet. I'm about to try an HTC Evo as well and see if I can get anywhere with that...

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your device doesn't support the preview format that is being set in openCamera method of WebcamFacade.java at SL4A.

I have changed it by ImageFormat.NV21 that according with Android docs is always supported and it worked for me!

You can download this change from here:

https://code.google.com/r/olapaola-android-scripting/