# Issue with WebCamFacade in SL4A

Tags: python, sl4a

I'm having the same issue as this user.
[setParameters failed when initializing android webcam with python and SL4A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159483/setparameters-failed-when-initializing-android-webcam-with-python-and-sl4a)

I'm sure Paola G's response resolved the issue. My question is where does the updated WebCamFacade.java need to be placed? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I have googled for hours on how to fix this and I'm coming up blank.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own SL4A.apk with my updated WebCamFacade following this instructions and install it in your phone instead of the one you have:

http://jokar-johnk.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/how-to-make-android-app-with-sl4a.html

Instead of cloning from https://rjmatthews62-android-scripting.googlecode.com/hg/, clone it from this version that include the bug fixed:

**hg clone https://olapaola@code.google.com/r/olapaola-android-scripting/**